# WPF StaticResource vs DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, resources, staticresource, dynamicresource

I have my Xaml as below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushMe" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FreezeBrushMe" po:Freeze="true"  Color="Yellow"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>        
    <Button Background="{StaticResource BrushMe}">Static</Button>
    <Button Background="{DynamicResource BrushMe}">Dynamic</Button>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">ChangeColorProperty</Button>
    <Button Click="Button1_Click">ChangeBrushObject</Button>
    <!--<Button Background="{StaticResource NotExistResource}" Click="Button_Click_1">GenerateResourceForStatic</Button>-->
    <Button Background="{DynamicResource NotExistResource}" Click="Button_Click_1">GenerateResourceForDynamic</Button>
    <Button Background="Green" Click="Button_Click_1">FixedBrush</Button>
    <Button Background="{StaticResource FreezeBrushMe}">FreezeBrushStatic</Button>
    <Button Background="{DynamicResource FreezeBrushMe}">FreezeBrushDynamic</Button>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_2">ChangeFreezeColorProperty</Button>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_3">ChangeFreezeBrushObject</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In my code behind, it looks like

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)this.FindResource("BrushMe");
        brush.Color = Colors.Blue;
        this.Resources["BrushMe"] = brush;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush newBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        this.Resources["BrushMe"] = newBrush;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resources.Add("NotExistResource", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)this.FindResource("FreezeBrushMe");
        brush.Color = Colors.Blue;
        this.Resources["FreezeBrushMe"] = brush;
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush newBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        this.Resources["FreezeBrushMe"] = newBrush;
    }
```

My question is if I click ChangeBrushObject button first, it will change the Dynamic Button to Yellow, then I click ChangeColorProperty button, it will only change the Dynamic Button to Blue, and not affecting the Static button.

However, if I click the ChangeColorProperty button on its own, it will change both Static and Dynamic buttons to Blue.

Why it behaves like this? WPF doesn't throw any warnings when trying to assign a new object to a resource that has been referenced as static resource by the control?

I also tested the non-existing resource referenced by Dynamic Resource. As expected, if a StaticResource references a non-existing resource, Xaml will complain at compile time and DynamicResource does not. However, if I click GenerateResourceForDynamic button, it shows the green color as the background, but then it fades away, and reappears again, and repeats. Why it happens like this?

**Edit:** Added Freeze resource, strange behaviour again. If I click ChangeFreezeColorProperty button, it will through exception. And if I click ChangeFreezeBrushObject alone, it will change the FreezeBrushDynamic button color. However if I click ChangeFreezeBrushObject and then click ChangeFreezeColorProperty, no exception is thrown.

I think making a resource freeze will make the properties of the object linked with the resource to be readonly. that is why when changing the property, it will through the exception complaining about the readonly state. However freeze doesn't stop us from changing the object itself.

Comment: To your last question... No clue. It's weird that the color appears and disappears like that... Maybe it has something to do with the mouse hovering over the button?

Comment: To your first question... Modifying Resources is ok unless the Resource is frozen. If frozen, `brush.Color = Colors.Blue` would throw an exception. `StaticResource` has nothing to do with that, what's static is not the Resource itself, but the reference. `StaticResource` means you're creating a static reference to an instance of the Resource, that can be frozen or not.

Comment: To last question: It looks like standard animation for focused button in Aero theme

Comment: @Aloraman If I fix the color with Green in Xaml, the color only fade away when the mouse hovers over the button. But in my case, the color appears and disappears even the mouse is not hovering the button.

Comment: @almulo I have modified my question and added some test for Freeze attribute. I think when changing the resource from code behind to reference a new object, the StaticResource will stay in a "stale" state and it is no longer related to the new object assigned to the resource it is referencing. This can be approved by clicking the ChangeBrushObject button and then click ChangeColorProperty button.

Comment: @Helic Yep, I guess it works like that. When you replace a Resource from code-behind, you're simply assigning the Resource ID to the new object, but the old object is still referenced by the StaticResource references created prior to the change. Meanwhile, DynamicResource references connect to whatever object has the ID. Makes sense.